# How to subscribe to Windows ForwardedEvents Log with Powershell?

Tags: windows, powershell, logging

so I want to trigger an action every time a new event occurs in the ForwardedEvents Log in windows with my powershell script.

I found the following code to subscribe to Application Log, but this does not work for the ForwardedEvent log

```
$Name = 'Application'

# get an instance
$Log = [System.Diagnostics.EventLog]$Name

# determine what to do when an event occurs
$Action = {
    # do something when a new ecent occurs
}

# subscribe to its "EntryWritten" event
$job = Register-ObjectEvent -InputObject $log -EventName EntryWritten -SourceIdentifier 'NewEventHandler' -Action $Action
```

The error I get when trying this code with "ForwardedEvents" as name is:

```
Register-ObjectEvent : The event log 'ForwardedEvents' on computer '.' does not exist.
```

Thank you for any help!

EDIT:

My ForwardedEvent Log is active and filled with events. I use Windows 10 for this.

Comment: my `ForwardedEvents` log is listed in EventViewer as both `disabled` & with zero content. `Get-EventLog -LogName *` _does not list that event log at all_. i suspect that you will need to enable it somehow ... but i do not know how to do that via a script. [*blush*]

Comment: Hey, thanks for the input. I have a working Event Forwarded so my ForwardingEventsL Log is filled with events and active.
But I also can't list it with the `Get-EventLog -LogName *` Command

Comment: you are most welcome! [*grin*] my only idea is to check the permissions on the event log. perhaps it's one that requires some special permission?